# Does urn-, url-, and uri-encoding all refer to the same thing?

Tags: web-applications, url, character-encoding, uri

Can someone clarify if URN, URI, and URL encoding are all infact the same thing?

What term is most correct to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they all refer to the same thing. The encoding was originally defined in [RFC 1738](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt), section 2.2, and hence called "URL encoding". The URN RFC (2141) also defines that encoding, in section 2.3.1.  According to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-1.1.3), the correct term is typically URI (especially when talking about the general thing). This RFC defines the Percent-Encoding in section 2.1.